# Rewriting the values in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an app that allows the user to change the language of some content between English and Welsh. The following is used to populate an `NSMutableArray` called **comments**. The first time the code is used it works fine but if the language is subsequently changed the **comments** array will not load up the different set of comments. I suspect I need to clear the `NSMutableArray` each visit to the code. Firstly, is this the case? If so how do I do that if **comments = nil** does not do this?

```
+ (NSMutableArray *)comments {
static NSMutableArray *comments = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

if ([language isEqualToString: @"Eng"])
{
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
comments = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
               @"Eng1",
               @"Eng2",
               @"Eng3",
               nil];
    });
}

if ([language isEqualToString: @"Wel"])
{
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
comments = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                @"Welsh 1",
                @"Welsh 2",
                @"Welsh 3",
                nil];
    });
}

return comments;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dispatch_once` makes a block execute once **ever** for the lifetime of your whole application.

Instead, you probably just wanted to do a simple `nil` check.

```
static NSMutableArray *comments = nil;
+ (NSMutableArray *)comments {
  if (!comments)
  {
    if ([language isEqualToString: @"Eng"])
    {
      comments = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                  @"Eng1",
                  @"Eng2",
                  @"Eng3",
                  nil];
    }
    else if ([language isEqualToString: @"Wel"])
    {
      comments = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                  @"Welsh 1",
                  @"Welsh 2",
                  @"Welsh 3",
                  nil];
    }
  }
  return comments;
}

+ (void)changeLanguage:(NSString *)newLanguage {
  language = newLanguage;
  comments = nil;
}
```